# What topological space is the Earth?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The main character in Ted Chiang's "Tower of Babylon" discovers the shape of the world. He digs upward through what he believes to be the vault of the heavens only to exit a cave near the base of the tower.

If we imagine the Earth as a hollow ball with some non-trivial thickness (i.e $S^2\times I$) and we identify each point "at the top" of the form $(s,1)$  with the point $(s,0)$ directly beneath it, then I can see that the resulting space is $S^2\times S^1$.

I would like to do away with the assumption that the Earth is hollow and use the three-dimensional ball as the starting point. For instance, what would happen if we identify each boundary point of the ball with an interior point directly below it, as if projecting the boundary onto a small $S^2$ whose center is the center of the Earth? What is the (homotopy type of) the resulting topological space?

If you can think of other reasonable ways to interpret the topology described in the story, I'd be interested in hearing those too.